# how to obtain key pair values from an API JSON column - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas

after exploring one row in an API example, I found the whole information

`df['items'][0]`

```
{'tags': ['perl'],
 'owner': {'reputation': 93,
  'user_id': 6536089,
  'user_type': 'registered',
  'accept_rate': 0,
  'profile_image': 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f8b30a65d171e2a305745589dc02caba?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
  'display_name': 'andy',
  'link': 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/6536089/andy'},
 'score': 0,
 'last_activity_date': 1658173974,
 'creation_date': 1658110836,  # <----
 'last_edit_date': 1658173974, # <----
 'question_id': 73016722}
```

I been using this code to obtain the `creation_date` values:

```
df['items'].apply(lambda value : value['creation_date'] if isinstance(value, dict) else np.nan)
```

**Here is where I got stuck.** I found that some rows doesn't have **last_edit_date** values.

When I try to run the same code using the name **last_edit_date**  I get an error.

```
df['items'].apply(lambda value : value['last_edit_date'] if isinstance(value, dict) else np.nan)
```

> KeyError: 'last_edit_date'

Comment: Use [`value.get('last_edit_date')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead which will not raise a `KeyError` if the key does not exist within `value`. You can also supply a default value to return if the key is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code a lot by using [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

Given:

```
                                               items
0  {'tags': ['perl'], 'owner': {'reputation': 93,...
```

Doing:

```
df['last_edit_date'] = df['items'].str.get('last_edit_date')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                               items  last_edit_date
0  {'tags': ['perl'], 'owner': {'reputation': 93,...      1658173974
```